# What is the probability of extracting a fixed number x from a pool of n different numbers given k trials?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

Basically, I'm wondering if i have numbers from 1 to n what is the probability of extracting the number i'm looking for (x for example) if I am given k trials? Important thing to mention is that after each failed trial the number extracted will be removed from the pool of numbers

It is not necessary to go through all the k trials. Once x has been withdrawn you stop there.

n = 10, k = 4 
Successful example#1: 6 4 3 2 
Successful example#2: 9 2 
Failure example: 4 3 1 7

Comment: How many ways are there to draw $k$ numbers?  How many of them include $x$?

Comment: @LebowskiLebowski You are being given a hint, so think it through some more.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter if you stop when you get x or not. You succes hold.
Think of drawing k numbers.

Comment: Another approach is to calculate the probability NOT to extract the number you are looking for...